# Can't understand why this sentence is written this way

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

The sentence I am talking about is ジュースが出る大きいな桃 .

I don't understand why 大きいな桃 is written at the end. I would say something like:

ジュースが大きいな桃から出る

Thanks

Comment: As user3856370 mentioned in the answer, 大きいな桃 is a typo. Probably this one is written with 体言止め. The impression on me is peach is so flesh that you can drink juice from it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've been reading this [this article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012640461000/k10012640461000.html).

ジュースが出る大きいな桃 comes from a news headline and it is not a full sentence. Just like in English headlines you don't normally write full sentences.

It's simply a noun phrase: a description of a peach.

> Big peach that juice comes from.

I haven't read the article but (from the picture) you might imagine the full sentence would be something like "There is a shop with a big peach that juice comes out of". Not a very snappy headline.

Maybe I should explain the grammar too. 桃 is being modified by two things. The first is a simple na-adjective,　大きな (note that there is a typo in your sentence 大き**い**な). The second is a full sentence called a relative clause ジュースが出る. In Japanese full sentences/phrases can modify nouns just like adjectives.

Comment: Just a note on terminology, but a relative clause is not a full sentence. You could call it a verb phrase instead.

Comment: @kandyman Sorry, only just seen your comment. I think I must have had some terminology confusion for a long time. Are you saying ジュースが出る is not a relative clause? It's a peach **that** juice comes out of. I've always thought of things which come after 'that', 'which' etc as relative clauses. Am I wrong? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No I’m saying exactly that, i.e. it’s a relative clause. You seemed to imply that a relative clause was a type of sentence. In terms of hierarchy, a clause is lower than a sentence.

Comment: In other words ジュースが出る。 on its own is a full sentence. As a relative clause modifying something, it is no longer a full sentence.

Comment: @kandyman Okay. I didn't mean to imply that. Perhaps I didn't phrase it as well as I could have. Thanks.